# Merging 2 PDO arrays and sorting by shared column

Tags: php, pdo

I have 2 different queries, which return different PDO (FETCH_ASSOC) arrays:

```
$stmt1->execute();
$stmt2->execute();
```

Each array is returning results from 2 different tables, with different columns, however they have a common column: **date**(**timestamp**, which is stored in this format: **2018-04-28 20:31:23**).
Is it possible to sort the results by the date (descending or ascending) to echo the results sorted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by merging both arrays and sort the result with custom sort function.

Let's say `$rows1` represents rows of `$stmt1` and `$rows2` represents rows of `$stmt2`. The resulting array will be:

```
$rows = array_merge($rows1, $rows2);
```

Now you can sort the resulting array with [`usort` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php):

```
usort($rows, function (array $r1, array $r2) { ... });
```

where `function (array $r1, array $r2)` is the comparison function.

In case you're using PHP7 comparison function can be like this:

```
function (array $r1, array $r2) {
    $format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';

    $t1 = DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat($format, $r1['date']);
    $t2 = DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat($format, $r2['date']);

    return $t1 <=> $t2;
}
```

As you can see, it's convenient to use [spaceship operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.spaceship-op) for comparing objects of built-in [`DateTimeImmutable` class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php).

For PHP 5 it will be a bit longer:

```
function (array $r1, array $r2) {
    $format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';

    $t1 = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $r1['date']);
    $t2 = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $r2['date']);

    if ($t1 == $t2) {
        return 0;
    }

    return ($t1 > $t2) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

The whole example for PHP7:

```
// rows fetched from $stmt1
$rows1 = [
    ['id' => 1001, 'date' => '2018-04-26 08:00:00'],
    ['id' => 1002, 'date' => '2018-04-28 20:11:23'],
    ['id' => 1003, 'date' => '2018-04-28 20:31:23'],
];

// rows fetched from $stmt2
$rows2 = [
    ['id' => 2001, 'date' => '2018-04-27 08:00:00'],
    ['id' => 2002, 'date' => '2018-04-28 20:21:23'],
];

// the resulting array
$rows = array_merge($rows1, $rows2);

// sort the resulting array with our custom sort function
usort($rows, function (array $r1, array $r2) {
    $format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';

    $t1 = DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat($format, $r1['date']);
    $t2 = DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat($format, $r2['date']);

    return $t1 <=> $t2;
});
```

And the output will be sorted array as we expect:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1001
            [date] => 2018-04-26 08:00:00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2001
            [date] => 2018-04-27 08:00:00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1002
            [date] => 2018-04-28 20:11:23
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2002
            [date] => 2018-04-28 20:21:23
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1003
            [date] => 2018-04-28 20:31:23
        )

)
```

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I found another solution at the end, but I will mark this as solved because it looks like a good workaround